# C++ function with an istream& parameter

Tags: c++, istream

I would like my program to read a file using the function "readFile" below. I am trying to find out how to call a function with an istream& parameter. The goal of the function is to read the file by receiving the file's name as parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool readFile(std::istream& fileName); //error 1 this line

int main(void)
{   
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    readFile(fileName); //error 2 this line


}

bool readFile(std::istream& fileName)
{
    ifstream file(fileName, ios::in); //error 3 this line
    return true;
}
```

The three errors I get:

error 1 : in passing argument 1 of 'bool readFile(std::istream&)

error 2 : invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream&}' from expression of type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}

error 3 : invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Is there anyway I can fix it? The parameter of the function really has to remain "std::istream& fileName".

Thanks for helping.

Comment: A filename is usually a `std::string`, not a stream itself.

Comment: I think your teacher wants you to pass `file` to `readFile` and then do the file reading inside of `readFile`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's say I want the user to enter a file name and then call the function which accepts an &istream parameter (not a string) with that file name (string), how could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decide whether you're going to pass a string, or a file name. If you pass a string, then the caller needs to pass the string, and the function needs to be written to expect a file name.

If you decide to pass a stream, the caller needs to open and pass the stream, and the function needs to be written expecting a stream that it'll just use.

option A:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool readFile(std::string const &fileName);

int main(void)
{   
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    readFile(fileName);
}

bool readFile(std::string const &fileName)
{
    ifstream file(fileName);
    return true;
}
```

Option B:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool readFile(std::istream& file);

int main(void)
{   
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream file(fileName);
    readFile(file);
}

bool readFile(std::istream& fileName)
{
    return true;
}
```

Either one can work -- you just need to be consistent between the caller and callee. By strong preference, you want to be as consistent as possible throughout a given code base as well.

Comment: This makes a lot more sens, thanks a lot sir. But now I am getting this error : no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)
on "ifstream file(fileName)" line and I do not really understand what's wrong? Talking about the option B.

Comment: @Alex: Your compiler (or standard library, really) is apparently out of date. If you can't update to a current compiler, you can use `ifstream file(fileName.c_str());`

Comment: It is not about "out of date compiler/library" - std::string is allowed only since C++11 which support still has to be turned on explicitly in many compilers. Before C++11, there just was not such constructor for 'std::ifstream' which accepted 'std::string'.

Comment: @ArthurP.Golubev: Given that it's currently 2017, I think "out of date" is a fair and reasonable characterization of something that fails to support C++11. I think the same was true in 2014 when this answer was written. If you honestly disagree, I'll be happy to sell you some lottery tickets at a 50% discount. They're from last week's lottery, but (as you've defined things) that doesn't mean they're out of date.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, I am honestly disagree, because it is not about time at all and not about his compiler capabilities. His compiler most likely is able to accept the code and most likely was to compile it three years ago when he tried too - but an additional parameter should have been specified to get it working. For instance, at present, in 2017, some compilers still require -std=c++11 flag - you personally probably don't need to concern about it because your IDE does.